# Printing permutations from raw_input without brackets and commas?

Tags: python

I want to make the output of my code without brackets and commas:

```
import itertools
import pprint
run = 1
while run != 0:
    number = raw_input('\nPlease type between 4 and 8 digits and/or letters to run permutation: ')

    if len(number) >= 4 and len(number) <= 8:
        per = list(itertools.permutations(number))
        pprint.pprint(per)
        print '\nNumber of possible combinations: ',len(per),'\n'

    elif number == 'exit':
        run = 0

    else:
        raw_input('length must be 4 to 8 digits and/or letters. Press enter to exit')
        run = 0
```

So it prints out a list with each combination in a new line. How do I print it without getting the brackets and commas? I still want to be able to call per[x] to get a certain combination. Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: "without getting the brackets and commas"

Could you give an example of what format you want to see?  Should each line only contain digits (separated by spaces, e.g. `0 1 2 3`), or should each line look like the repr for the entry in the list (e.g. `(0, 1, 2, 3)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `join()`

```
per = list(itertools.permutations(number))
        for x in per:
            print "".join(x)
        print '\nNumber of possible combinations: ',len(per),'\n'
```

Comment: This is the output I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: Note that `join`, (at least in python 3.x) does not do implicit string conversion of objects, so this code isn't future proof (though the print statement implies this).  Guido himself gave the rational for [why there is no implicit string conversion](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-October/008358.html) -- to detect buggy code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pprint.pprint`, which will print the repr of an object, you should use the regular print, which will not change newlines to a literal `'\n'`:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, per)))
```

Had to map `str` over `per`, as `string.join` expects a list of strings.

**Edit**: Example output shows each permutation is not separated by commas, and you do not see the bracket for the list:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str, itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3]))))
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 3, 2)
(0, 2, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2, 3)
(1, 0, 3, 2)
(1, 2, 0, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 0, 2)
(1, 3, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1, 3)
(2, 0, 3, 1)
(2, 1, 0, 3)
(2, 1, 3, 0)
(2, 3, 0, 1)
(2, 3, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 1, 2)
(3, 0, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 0, 2)
(3, 1, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 0, 1)
(3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `pprint.pprint` with something like:

```
for line in per:
    print ''.join(line)
```

Here's a more compact version of your code snippet:

```
import itertools

while True:
    user_input = raw_input('\n4 to 8 digits or letters (type exit to quit): ')
    if user_input == 'exit':
        break
    if 4 <= len(user_input) <= 8:
        # no need for a list here, just unfold on the go
        # counting via enumerate
        for i, p in enumerate(itertools.permutations(user_input)):
            print(''.join(p))
        print('#permutations: %s' % i)
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helps me see the easy changes I can make to get my code more compact. Great addition!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them and print each one separated by the character you like (here space):

```
#pprint.pprint(per)
for p in per:
    print ' '.join(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace pprint() with your own bit of code to output the data.  Something like this:

```
for i in per:
    print i
```

Comment: I tried :

    for i in per:
        print i

I still get parantheses and commas. I want the output without it.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the list to a string then remove the brackets and commas:

```
x = str(per)[1 : -1]
x.replace(",", "")
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Other variation of the answer

`(lambda x: ''.join(x))(x)`